# Long term medication and increased risk for CLL?

Tags: medications, cancer, heart-attack

Is a person on long term medication (aspirin, bisoprolol,vitamin B1/B6/B12, simvastatin and trimetazidine) because of a heart attack 30 years ago (and no positive family history) at increased risk of developing Chronic Lymphocytic Leukaemia (CLL)?

Comment: Hi! Just to be sure that I understood your question correctly: you want to know if a person with a coronary heart disease, under ASA, betablocker, furosemide, statin has an increased risk for developing chronic lymphocytic leukaemia? I am right? May I ask you why you are asking for this typical hematological malignancy? You may also wish considering editing your title which is somehow inconsistent with your question (too broad for a very specific question). Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: Hi, I am asking this question because I know of someone who has a heart condition and been taking these medicines for some years now. The person has now been diagnosed with chronic lymphocytic leukaemia. As mentioned in my earlier post this person has no family history of cancer nor any lifestyle issue that puts the person in the risk category for cancer.

Comment: Ok. I have answered your question. I will also edit a little bit your question. As already suggested in my first comment, the title is inconsistent with your question and can be misleading as you are asking about CLL in particular and not cancer. And as a side note: when asking a question on Health SE, it is better to write the compound name of a drug and not its market name, which can be different from one country to another. Hope this helps. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Answer (score 2):

According to the literature, risk factors for chronic lymphocytic leukaemia (CLL) are:

- **gender**: CLL is more frequent in men than in women
- **age**: CLL is considered to be mainly a disease of older adults, with a
  median age at diagnosis of 70 years. Although younger individuals (in their 30s-40s) can develop CLL, the incidence rises dramatically with age
- **ethnicity**: studies have shown that the incidence of CLL varies by
  race and geographic location: it is higher in caucasians and lower in
  African Americans or Asian Pacific Islanders.
- **genetic/positive family history**: the cytogenetic and molecular genetic characteristics of CLL appear to be similar throughout the world suggesting a common genetic alteration. Also, CLL  occur with higher frequency among first-degree family members of patients with CLL.

Finally, **no clear discernible occupational or environmental risk factors that predispose to CLL have been identified yet**. Also, no long term medication has been associated with the development of CLL.

Sources:
http://www.uptodate.com/contents/clinical-presentation-pathologic-features-diagnosis-and-differential-diagnosis-of-chronic-lymphocytic-leukemia